# ComboBox text change failure

Tags: c#, datagrid, combobox, toolstripmenu

I am calling the following on `ToolStripMenu` item click :

```
protected void windowNewMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (_selectedThings.Contains(((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Tag))
     {
        selectedItemsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Tag;
        selectedItemsComboBox.SelectedText = (((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Tag.GetType()).ToString();
     }
    }
```

However the second line that is supposed to change does not seem to produce any visible changes to the `ComboBox`. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedText` is for highlighting a portion of the text, not selecting an *item* in the list.  For that, you need `SelectedItem`.

Or you can just use:

```
selectedItemsComboBox.Text = ...
```